# Ubuntu Advantage virtual server rotation

Tags: server, virtualization, ubuntu-advantage

I want to get Ubuntu Advantage licence for virtual servers.  Some of those servers are in an AWS auto-scaling group. The maximum number of servers is fixed, but there may be less running, and they get rotated regularly (daily).  How does the licence work with old servers being torn down and new ones coming up?  Does the server count mean concurrent running servers or is the usage tied to a box as soon as it is attached?

Would I need to explicitly `ua detach` the server before it is shut down?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, yes there is the detach command to detach the account:

```
COMMANDS
       attach [--no-auto-enable] <token>
              Connect an Ubuntu Advantage support contract to this machine.

              The token parameter can be obtained from https://auth.contracts.canonical.com/.

              The optional --no-auto-enable flag will disable the automatic enablement of recommended entitlements which usually happens immediately after a successful attach.

       detach Remove the Ubuntu Advantage support contract from this machine. This also disables all enabled services that can be.
```

Until we get a definitive official answer, this is the safe bet that it is required.

In the future, they might remove this constraint, for example by rate-limiting up to the server count in an account the various subscribed services, but so far I can not find such feature announcement.